# Math-operations (or hash functions) without order dependency

Tags: math, hash, cryptography

The problem I am thinking about is hash functions, although I'm mainly interested in the mathematical terms/background to describe my requested property.

Consider the case where I have a hash-function taking a secret (**S**) and a number (**X**) which creates another number (**Y**):

```
Hash : S, X → Y
```

I then define two different hash-functions with their own secrets (**a** and **b**):

```
H1(X) := Hash(a, X)
H2(X) := Hash(b, X)
```

The property I want is that:

```
H1(H2(x)) = H2(H1(X))
```

(I think this is called that the functions commute?)

Taking a step back from programming and thinking about math we can look at different operations. If the function consist of one operation only, then I'm quite sure that this property will always be satisfied if the operation has both associative and commutative properties. However there are operations which are order insensitive but non-commutative, e.g. division. How does I know if my choice of hash function will make it commute?

Some examples that seems to work:

Simple addition:

```
Hash(S, X) := S + X
```

Bitwise xor:

```
Hash(S, X) := S xor X
```

Modular exponentiation:

```
Hash(S, X) := X^S mod p
if S ∈ N and X ∈ Z￼
```

Comment: [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895212/what-is-the-term-given-to-two-functions-when-their-order-of-composition-does-not) indicates that "commutativity" is fine...but it should be clearly understood as "commutativity of the hash functions (and their embedded secrets) with respect to the composition operator".

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know if my choice of hash function will make it commute?

Commutativity under composition is an unusual property. It's not typical unless the functions are using a commutative operation of some underlying algebraic structures, such as "multiply by `x`". This is the form of your three examples.

The practical answer is "if you don't have a proof that it's commutative, assume it's not commutative". There's no general algorithm that will provide that proof for you.